# Changing background color for countries based on data

Tags: highcharts

I have a json list of countries, that each has a status *not updated*, or *updated*.

I want to show different background colors for the countries, based on their status.

```js
$(function() { 

var criticalStatusData=[{"Country":"Australia","Criticality_High":40,"Criticality_Medium":294,"Criticality_Low":62,"LocationLiveStatus":"Live"}]; 


var mapData = Highcharts.maps['custom/world']; 

$('#container').highcharts('Map', { 
chart: { 
events: { 
load: function() { 
this.series[0].data = this.series[0].data.map((el) => { 
if (el['LocationLiveStatus'] == "Live") { 
el.color = "#ff0000"; 
return el; 
} 
return el 
}) 

this.update({ 
series: [{ 
data: this.series[0].data 
}] 
}) 
} 
} 
}, 
series: [{ 
name: 'Countries', 
mapData: mapData, 
data: criticalStatusData 
}], 
legend: { 
enabled: false 
}, 
title: { 
text: 'World map' 
} 
}); 

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks but in my casse its not useful because they are not providing any condition...

Comment: Make a [**load event**](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.events.load) where you loop through all your countries and their status. Then color that country based on the status.

Comment: Its not working...

Comment: Do u have any example..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862672/coloring-a-country-in-lat-long-highmap?rq=1 this can be used. There specific contries are colored, you could do that, or all countries.

Comment: Iam using the data manually but here they are using mapdata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179176/discussion-between-nayeem-shaiky-and-ewolden).

Comment: This is how you need to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/t9cus12b/14/

Comment: Great... Thank you so much ewolden....

Comment: To improve performance, you can use `Point.update()` instead of assigning new series through `chart.update()`. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/bcaspq31/

Comment: Thank you daniel_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding custom data as a separate series, it is possible to use the load event to tell if a country should be in one state or the other. Can be done like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.series[1].data.length; i++) {
        this.series[0].data.forEach((el) => {
          if (el['name'] == this.series[1].data[i].Country) {
            if(this.series[1].data[i].LocationLiveStatus == 'Live'){
                el.update({color: "#ff0000"}, false);
            }
          }
          return el
        })
      }
      this.redraw();
    }
  }
},
```

Thanks to [@daniel_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8547775/daniel-s) for making the query more efficient, by only updating the affected points and not the whole series.

```js
$(function() {

  var criticalStatusData = [{
    "Country": "Australia",
    "Criticality_High": 40,
    "Criticality_Medium": 294,
    "Criticality_Low": 62,
    "LocationLiveStatus": "Live"
  }];


  var mapData = Highcharts.maps['custom/world'];

  $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.series[1].data.length; i++) {
            this.series[0].data.forEach((el) => {
              if (el['name'] == this.series[1].data[i].Country) {
               if(this.series[1].data[i].LocationLiveStatus == 'Live'){
                 el.update({color: "#ff0000"}, false);
                }
              }
              return el
            })
          }
          this.redraw();
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Countries',
      mapData: mapData,

    }, {
      name: 'Countries options',
      visible: false,
      data: criticalStatusData
    }],
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'World map'
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```