# Color coutries/continents with own custom colors in highmaps

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a basic representation of world map using highmaps. If I have two types of maps, [countries](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/world-eckert3-highres) and [continents](https://jsfiddle.net/qdc8fk91/).

```
var data = [
    ['eu', 0], 
    ['oc', 1],
    ['af', 2],
    ['as', 3],
    ['na', 4],
    ['sa', 5], 
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'custom/world-continents'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-continents.js">World continents</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    plotOptions: {
    map: {
        allAreas: false,
    }
  },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
    }]
});
```

this is how I display maps. What I want to do is color some specific parts of the map with any color I want. For eg. I just want to color Europe and not the rest of the map, or I want to color only France and leave the rest of the map uncolored.
what I did is, changed data array to have objects

```
data =[{name:"Europe", data:[{code: "eu", color: "#CCCCCC"}]},
{name:"Asia", data:[{code: "as", color: "#4A4444"}]},
{name:"Africa", data:[{code: "af", color: "#AC7070"}]},
{name:"Oceana", data:[{code: "oc", color: "#87AC70"}]},
{name:"North America", data:[{code: "na", color: "#70AC9F"}]},
{name:"South America", data:[{code: "sa", color: "#7094AC"}]}
```

and changed `joinBy:['code']` but it had no effect. Please give me ideas/suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can color a country/continent by replacing for example:

```
['eu', 0],
```

With:

```
{'hc-key': 'eu', value: 0, color: 'gold'},
```

Then that country/continent will be colored accordingly. `hc-key` is the important part of making this work (although not directly specified in the API).

If you are going to color based on other attributes you can use something like this: [Coloring a country in lat-long highmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862672/coloring-a-country-in-lat-long-highmap/48864054#48864054)

**Working JSfiddle example for a continent:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/8jxu6vtw/

Comment: that did help to much extent. thanks! Now I've got a tricky use case. sometimes, I'll have to show Europe in a different color and the middle east in a different one or east and west europe in different ones. I don't think they are covered in same map type. How to achieve this efficiently? should I use the world map and use countries?

Comment: Either you would then need to define (or find if it exists) shapes that fit to your specifications, I.e. East and west Europe, and apply the color to them. Far easier I would say is to make your own arrays for different definitions, then use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862672/coloring-a-country-in-lat-long-highmap/48864054#48864054 to programatically change color. I.e. check if hc-key is in a custom "West Europe" array, and if it is, color those countries. That is how I would solve it anyway...